# In TypeScript how to force inherited class to implement a method

Tags: class, oop, typescript

I need to force the class to implement some method for example `onCreate()`, as in other languages like `php` we can see something like:

```
<?php

// Declare the interface 'Movement'
interface MovementEvents
{
    public function onWalk($distance);
}

// Declare the abstract class 'Animal'
abstract class Animal implements MovementEvents{

    protected $energy = 100;

    public function useEnergy($amount){
        $energy -= $amount;
    }

}


class Cat extends Animal{

    // If I didn't implement `onWalk()` I will get an error
    public function onWalk($distance){

        $amount = $distance/100;

        $this->useEnergy($amount)

    }

}

?>
```

Note that in my example if I didn't implement `onWalk()` the code will not work and you will get an error but when I do the same in `TypeScript` as following:

```
// Declare the interface 'Movement'
interface MovementEvents
{
    onWalk: (distance)=>number;
}

// Declare the abstract class 'Animal'
abstract class Animal implements MovementEvents{

    protected energy:number = 100;

    public useEnergy(amount:number):number{

        return this.energy -= amount;

    }

}


class Cat extends Animal{

    // If I didnt implment `onWalk()` I will get an error
    public onWalk(distance:number):number{

        var amount:number = distance/100;

        return this.useEnergy(amount);

    }

}
```

No error will show whether I did or didn't implement the on walk method but the it will give an error if I didn't implement `onWalk()` in the `Animal` class, I need to have same as `php` in `TypeScript`?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You can declare your `Animal` class with the `abstract` keyword and same for the method you want to force in the child class.

```
abstract class Animal {
    abstract speak(): string;
}

class Cat extends Animal {
    speak() {
        return 'meow!';
    }
}
```

You can find more information about **abstract classes and methods** in the [TypeScript Handbook](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Handbook/blob/master/pages/Classes.md#abstract-classes).

Comment: Amazing thanks a lot .. I spent days searching for a solution.

Comment: abstract is the name of the game!

Comment: Does this work the same with class properties, too?

Comment: Worth noting that an abstract class cannot inherit from a non-abstract class. If you have multiple levels of inheritance, then this method may not work.

Answer (score 10):

As of TypeScript 1.6 you can now declare classes and method `abstract`. For example:-

```
abstract class Animal {
    abstract makeSound(input : string) : string;
}
```

Unfortunately the documentation hasn't caught up yet
https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v2.6.0/doc/spec.md#8-classes

Comment: Thanks that was very helpful